# How can I retrieve all the stored procedures and their input and output parameters in all the databases from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies, for a convoluted question - I'm not a dba. Is there a simple script I can run that can list all the stored procedures I have on SQL Server, grouped by database and list them with the input and output parameters that go with the stored procedures.

I'm writing a similar script outside of SQL, to do the same for a language calling the stored procedures, so I find if there are conflicts in a legacy application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following script:

```
DECLARE @CurrentRowID INT
       ,@CurrentDatabase SYSNAME;

DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##DataSource') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##DataSource;
END;

CREATE TABLE ##DataSource 
(
    [database] SYSNAME
   ,[procedure] SYSNAME
   ,[parameter] SYSNAME
   ,[is_output] BIT
);

DECLARE @DataBases TABLE
(
    [RowID] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,[database] SYSNAME
);

INSERT INTO @DataBases ([database])
SELECT [name]
FROM [sys].[databases];

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @DataBases)
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 1 @CurrentRowID = [RowID]
                ,@CurrentDatabase = [database]
    FROM @DataBases;

    SET @DynamicSQL = N'INSERT INTO ##DataSource
                         SELECT ''' + @CurrentDatabase + ''' AS [database]
                              ,PR.[name]
                              ,P.[name]
                              ,P.[is_output]
                        FROM [' + @CurrentDatabase + '].[sys].[procedures] PR
                        INNER JOIN [' + @CurrentDatabase + '].[sys].[parameters] P
                            ON PR.[object_id] = P.[object_id]'

    EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQL;


    DELETE FROM @DataBases
    WHERE [RowID] = @CurrentRowID;
END;

SELECT *
FROM ##DataSource
```

Of course, you can filter some of the databases, or add more columns from the `sys.procedures` dmv like system type for example.

Answer (score 0):

Run a loop/cursor on sys.databases and inside the loop, USE  and run the following query and keep taking union:

```
SELECT pr.name [Procedure], par.name Parameter, CASE WHEN is_output = 1 THEN 'Output Parameter' ELSE 'Input Parameter' END [ParameterType]
FROM sys.parameters par
INNER JOIN sys.procedures pr ON pr.object_id = par.object_id
ORDER BY [Procedure], [ParameterType]
```

This will give you all procedures and their dependent parameters.

Answer (score 0):

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

set @sql = @sql + N'union all 
select '''+ quotename(d.name) + N''' as db, s.name as sname, p.name as p.name,  r. name as paramname, r.is_output as paramoutput 
from '''+ quotename(d.name) + N'''.sys.procedures p
join sys.parameters r on p.object_id = r.object_id
join sys.schemas s on p.schema_id = s.schema_id'
from sys.databases d
-- where d.name like  ....
order by d.name

set @sql = stuff@sql, 1, 10, N'') 
exec sp_executesql @sql

-- not tested